# Quickly estimating a probability

Tags: probability, estimation

Suppose I have five bins into which I want to place 15 balls. The bins have capacities $2$, $2$, $3$, $3$, and $7.$ I place the balls one at a time in the bins, randomly and uniformly amongst the bins that are not full (so for example, if after placing four balls, both of the bins with capacity $2$ are already full, the next ball is placed with probability $1/3$ in each of the remaining three bins).

My question is if there is a an efficient way to estimate the probability that the bin with capacity $7$ is full at the end of this process (it would be great if the technique generalizes in the obvious way).

Comment: $15$ is very close to the total capacity of the given bins, hence if at the end of the process the largest bin is full, it means that there are two different bins with a missing ball, or a single bin with $2$ missing balls. If you find a compact formula giving the probability of reaching a fixed configuration you are essentially done.

Comment: You may also try to reverse time, by starting with full bins and computing the probability that the first and second step a ball is *removed* from a particular bin.

Comment: So the wanted probability shouldn't deviate too much from $\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2$.

Comment: I am getting that the largest bin is full in approximately 9.25% of the runs on 1 million simulations of this scenario

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I don't understand: $16/25$ isn't anywhere close to the probability $p$ I want (or to $1-p$). Perhaps there is a typo?

Comment: @Stephen: no, it simply means by time-reversal approach was deeply flawed :D

Comment: @klumbard Yes, that is about right.

Comment: In that case, is "simulate it" a viable answer for you? It's pretty easy to implement

Comment: @klumbard No; I'm interested if there is a nice trick that can be used for mental calculation of similar probabilities. It's possible that there isn't.

Comment: Interesting question (+1)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like a good way to solve the general problem would be to use generating functions. Essentially, the total number of ways of distributing the balls to $\textit{distinct}$ bins can be thought of the number of solutions to $$k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4+k_5=15$$ such that 
$$0\leq k_1,k_2\leq 2$$
$$0\leq k_3,k_4\leq 3$$
$$0\leq k_5\leq 7$$

I believe the correct way to solve this using generating functions would be to find the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in the expanded form of $$(1+x+x^2)^2(1+x+x^2+x^3)^2(1+x +...+x^7)$$

Now, we need to know how many of these solutions have a full bin of $7$. This is just the number of solutions to 
$$k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4=8$$
with the same restrictions on all $k$. Once again you can use generating functions for this.

The ratio of these two counts should be the probability of a full bin of 7.

Comment: Correction: Since you are starting generating functions with $x^0$ that means that your $k_i$ have a lower bound of 0. And in fact, for this problem, $k_i \geq 0$ not $k_i \geq 1$. So you wrote the conditions incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you get a good estimate the coefficient of x^15?

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

**This is just a generalization of the answer by Bryce**

Suppose there are $m$ bins with capacities $n_i, i\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$. Suppose $N$ balls are to be placed in these bins randomly one at a time, such that each non-full bin has an equal chance of getting filled with the next ball. Suppose we were to find the probability that $k$th bin is full after all $N$ balls are placed.

Assuming $\sum_{i=1}^{m}n_i \geq N$, number of ways in which $N$ balls can be placed in $m$ bins is equal to the number of integral solutions of the equation,

$$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_m = N$$

such that $0 \leq x_i \leq n_i$. The number of integral solutions of this equation can be found by finding the coefficient of $x^N$ in,

$$\prod_{i=1}^{m}(1+x+\ldots+x^{n_i})$$

Let the coefficient of $x^N$ in above polynomial be $C$.

Now, the number of ways in which $N$ balls can be filled in $m$ bins such that $k$th bin is full, is equal to the number of integral solutions of the equation,

$$x_1+x_2+\ldots+n_k+x_{k+1}+\ldots+x_m = N$$

such that $0 \leq x_i \leq n_i$. The number of integral solutions of this equation can be found by finding the coefficient of $x^{N-n_k}$ in,

$$\prod_{\substack{i=1\\i\neq k}}^{m}(1+x+\ldots+x^{n_i})$$

Let the coefficient of $x^{N-n_k}$ in above polynomial be $C_k$.

Then the required probability is $\frac{C_k}{C}$.